# Use a select within a select statement in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to execute the following query:

```
SELECT pt.prod_desc"Description",
(
 CASE
  WHEN pt.prod_level='2'
THEN 'Product'
WHEN pt.prod_level='4'
THEN 'Sub-Product'
WHEN pt.prod_level='5'
THEN 'Service'
ELSE 'N/A'
END)"Level", prod_id"CKC ID", isactive"Active", updt_usr_sid"Last Updated By", 
updt_ts"LAst Updated Date",
(CASE WHEN pt.prod_level='5' THEN parent_prod_id ELSE null END)"Parent Sub-Product CKC ID",
(CASE WHEN Level='Service' THEN (Select prod_desc from dims_prod_type where prod_id= parent_prod_id) ELSE 'N/A' END)
FROM dims_prod_type pt
  ORDER BY prod_desc;
```

I get the following error:
Error report:

> ```
> SQL Error: ORA-01788: CONNECT BY clause required in this query block
> 01788. 00000 -  "CONNECT BY clause required in this query block"
> *Cause:    
> *Action:
> ```

I modified my query to the following:

```
 SELECT pt.prod_desc"Description",
 (
 CASE
  WHEN pt.prod_level='2'
THEN 'Product'
WHEN pt.prod_level='4'
THEN 'Sub-Product'
WHEN pt.prod_level='5'
THEN 'Service'
ELSE 'N/A'
END)"Level", prod_id"CKC ID", isactive"Active", updt_usr_sid"Last Updated By", 
updt_ts"LAst Updated Date",
(CASE WHEN pt.prod_level='5' THEN parent_prod_id ELSE null END)"Parent Sub-Product CKC   ID",
(CASE WHEN Level='Service' THEN (Select prod_desc from dims_prod_type where connect by prior prod_id=parent_prod_id) ELSE 'N/A' END)
FROM dims_prod_type pt
  ORDER BY prod_desc;
```

Still getting the same error.

Comment: level keyword is reserved for oracle, try a different alias name

Comment: Use aliases to distinguish between two instances of the same table

Comment: got it. thanks! If i change the alias name it works.

Comment: Why would that matter when he double quoted the alias?

Comment: @DanBracuk When he got this error, it means, all the alias are valid! But I agree to your point. The requester _could have_ made some changes for posting for understanding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made two mistakes here:

1. You called a column with `level` Oracle reserved keyword
2. You are referring to `level` column in the same context it was created with the case/when: that column does not exists as a standalone column in that scope and cannot be referred in where/group by clauses, just in order by clauses